# TypeError in parsing har file in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, typeerror

I am getting the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" while parsing a har file in python using json. Here is my code:

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding = "utf8")
global data
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
entries = data["log"]["entries"]

for entry in entries:
url = urlparse(entry["request"]["url"])
domain = url.netloc 
entry["domain_name"] = domain
if domain in domain_dict:
    domain_dict[domain].extend(entry)
else:
    domain_dict[domain] = [entry]

for dom in domain_dict:
    for y in domain_dict[dom]:
        url_temp = y["request"]["url"]
        filetype = y["response"]["content"]["mimeType"]
```

I am getting the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in the line

```
url_temp = y["request"]["url"]
```

The error does not appear in every iteration in the loop.

Comment: y["request"] is a string not a dict

Comment: @AndreyF then how do I get the url from it?